# Override all table name convention in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby, activerecord

My project doesn't use the plural convention in table's names.
How can I override this convention 
without calling set_table_name in all my ActiveRecord class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to create an initializer in your rails project like this:

```
# file: config/initializers/active_record_extensions.rb

ActiveRecord::Base.pluralize_table_names = false
```

This will make all your table names singular by default on your models.

Answer (score 2):

If it is only specific tables and not all of them

self.pluralize_table_names = false

works well.